# проблема с кодировкой PSQL

Tags: postgresql, cmd, локаль, psql

Работаю в windows 10, в файле находится INSERT в с данными в базу postgresql, часть данных кириллицей написана. При импорте данных через cmd

```
user>psql -U postgres test < C:/Users/Documents/sql/data.sql
```

происходит корректное отображение данных в таблице psql (id 2, 3 таблицы). Но когда тот же самый файл импортирую через оболочку psql

```
# psql -U postgres test < \i C:/Users/Documents/sql/data.sql;
```

кириллические символы отображаются в psql уже как кракозябры (id 1, 4).

```
# select * from test_table_one;
 id |       name       | price |  description
----+------------------+-------+----------------
  1 | СЃРѕСЃРёСЃРѕРЅС‹ |  15.6 | Р№С†СѓРєРµРЅСЉ
  2 | сосисоны         |  15.6 | йцукенъ
  3 | сосисоны         |  15.6 | йцукенъ
  4 | СЃРѕСЃРёСЃРѕРЅС‹ |  15.6 | Р№С†СѓРєРµРЅСЉ
```

кодировка базы такая:

```
# \l
      Список баз данных
    Имя   | Владелец | Кодировка |     LC_COLLATE     |     LC_CTYPE        |
----------+----------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------
test      | postgres | UTF8      | Russian_Russia.1251| Russian_Russia.1251 |
```

psql encoding:

```
# SHOW client_encoding;
 client_encoding
-----------------
 WIN1251
(1 строка)
```

есть предположение, что это из-за локаля. Но как поменять его не знаю. Пробовал при создании базы указывать `LC_COLLATE='Russian_Russia.UTF8'` или `LC_COLLATE='ru_RU.UTF8'`, но psql таких значений не принимает, только `Russian_Russia.1251` или `Russian_Russia.866`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как брать данные из файла, находясь в psql, чтобы кириллица корректно отображалась.

Answer (score 6):

Внести изменение в начало файла SQL shell(psql) NOTEPAD++ в режиме администратора, добавив строку chcp 1251 (см. фрагмент ниже)

```
@echo off

REM Copyright (c) 2012-2020, EnterpriseDB Corporation.  All rights reserved

REM PostgreSQL server psql runner script for Windows

chcp 1251

SET server=localhost
SET /P server="Server [%server%]: "
....
```

Comment: дайте этому молодому человеку галочку за правильный ответ)

Comment: Уже дважды меня этот ответ выручил!

Answer (score 2):

1. run "SQL Shell (psql)"
2. postgres=# psql \! chcp 1251

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

В интерактивном режиме psql сам выбирает и устанавливает `client_encoding` в соответствии с настройками консоли, а в пакетном — он устанавливается сервером по умолчанию в кодировку базы (или в сохранённое значение).

На сколько я понимаю, файл в utf8, тогда есть два варианта:

- перекодировать в cp1251, но тогда сломается пакетный импорт
- сделай перед интерактивны импортом `SET client_encoding TO 'utf8'`, а лучше добавить это прямо в начало файла.

`LC_COLLATE`, как и одноимённая переменная ни как не определяет кодировку базы или соединения, а задаёт лишь порядок сортировки строк. Полный список возможных параметоров системно-зависим и можно посмотреть, например, в

```
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_collation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ввести команду в psql:

```
\\! chcp 1251
```